# $match expr in same document does not work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

How to transform the data using $if $else condition MongoDB

[mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OvuTNE16o8r)

I am getting worst digging into $if $expr condition

This playground should return nothing because date is $gt then main collection but it does return me data.

So condition should say if history's date is $gt then main collection should return nothing else return the matched criteria data.

Answer (score 0):

the first `history` record only is used, as it has the same `_id` as the `history_id` in the `main` collection

so if you check the first history document

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
  "user_id": "5e4e74eb380054797d9db625",
  "history_id": ObjectId("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
  "date": 1587650683433,
  "__v": 1
}
```

and your query

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "5e4e74eb380054797d9db623",
              "$History.user_id"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$date",
                  "$History.date"
                ]
              },
              { // also, this part has no meaning as the same condition is used in the if part
                $eq: [
                  "5e4e74eb380054797d9db623",
                  "$History.user_id"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          else: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

the if condition is not satisfied, as the user_id in history model `"5e4e74eb380054797d9db625"` does not equal to the specified id `"5e4e74eb380054797d9db623"`

so, it goes to the else part which is getting all the documents in the `main` collection

note: I've added some comment in the query, could you check it too?

Comment: Yes but its array object it should look for other object in second it does not how to fix it ?

Comment: how do you mean? sorry, could you explain what you needed in details, also add a sample of your data as it is?

Comment: we need to return nothing in the else part, you mean? instead of all documents?

Comment: you can see $history collection does have two object and one of them does match with specified id from user_id (history's collection) and if match date $gt main collection and history_id is same with main collection history_id should return nothing if found return that data

Comment: could you check the second history document?, its _id is "5e4e755b380054797d9db629" while the history_id in both documents in main collection is "5e4e755b380054797d9db627"

Comment: that's why you got all the data, as the first history record only is used not the second

Comment: My bad to explain yeah as your point you are fine but the field name says history_id in both they both matched for the sake of this I wrote ...

Comment: it's better to reference to the _id of the history document as it's unique, here in your case, you need to refer to all the documents that the same history_id

Comment: could you explain the requirements in more details, please? :)

Comment: See https://mongoplayground.net/p/kq8h9JHS77q This is my problem, I have 1000 number of document in main collection and now I need to create ew collection names history based on history_id i am doing lookup from main collection to history collection. when two document inserted with same history_id into history collection it shows me all record that not required.

Now i fedup what to do for this uniqueness for both collection please guide

Comment: I suggest you to create the history records first, then take the _id from it (As it's unique) and update the main documents with that history _id, after that, you will do the lookup only to one history document

Comment: First of all thanks for you effort and time I created a new question please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497153/how-to-use-groupby-and-transform-distinct-value-mongodb

Comment: Please join when you're avail https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212625/discussion-on-answer-by-mohammed-yousry-playing-around-with-mongodb-expr-gt-an

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong I guess this is what you're expecting :-

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$_id",
              "$History.user_id"
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              "$date",
              "$Histoy.date"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Well, few modification might be needed to fulfill  your need.

Comment: you're checking if the main document _id is equal to the history.user_id which is impossible to return any data!, the first condition in the $and operator will be always false I think, as the main document _id cannot be the same as the history.user_id

Comment: @MohammedYousry The reason I mention he need to modify the code according to his need as this is the architecture that he need to follow for suitable outcome and instead of writing the complex code he wrote.