# how to use $groupby and transform distinct value mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

How to transform the data using `$if $else` groupby condition MongoDB?

This playground should return two object who belongs to text with "tester 2" and "tester 3" also if I have multiple object in history collection it should also check with last object not will all object how it is possible

So condition should say if history's date is `$gt` then main collection should return nothing else return the matched criteria data.

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "history_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "5e4e74eb380054797d9db623",
              "$History.user_id"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$date",
                  "$History.date"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "5e4e74eb380054797d9db623",
                  "$History.user_id"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          else: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PbhVULWxCoe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it is what you are trying to do:

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      let: {
        main_history_id: "$history_id",
        main_user_id: { $toString: "$sender_id" }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$history_id",
                    "$$main_history_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$user_id",
                    "$$main_user_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$History",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1,
      "History.history_id": 1,
      "History.date": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: { $last: "$$ROOT" },
      History: { $last: "$History" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$data",
          { History: "$History" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              { $type: "$History.date" },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              "5e4e74eb380054797d9db623",
              "$History.user_id"
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "5e4e74eb380054797d9db623",
                  "$History.user_id"
                ]
              },
              {
                $gte: [
                  "$date",
                  "$History.date"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rz3_3HEyWJL)

Comment: Hi @Valijon if history collection is empty it should return all main collection detail and it only returns _id, date and text from main collection but it should return every data

Comment: Thanks need one more favour https://mongoplayground.net/p/GifjcWwl-LY see this if user_id does not match it also return everything

Comment: @SunilDubey Check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/1DNRG9y1zC_

Comment: @Vilijon can you do me a favour can't we setup lookup based on main collection's history_id and sender_id and history collection's user_id and history_id and then check compare with dates ? if possible please guide that will help

Comment: @SunilDubey Take a look https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup

Comment: @SunilDubey It would be the last requirements? You have changed several times OP.

Comment: Yes that's one help me

Comment: @SunilDubey Done. You need to have at least MongoDB v4.0, since `sender_id` is ObjectId type, but user_id is String.

Comment: this is final https://mongoplayground.net/p/J2e2ul_mJqM see this nothing should display in that case if history's date is greater than main collection date for both user if I change specified id, its working fine if I put 5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764 in specified id but does not work for 5e4e74eb380054797d9db623. Please guide in that scenario that would be great

Comment: This is one thing I am looking for hope you will help in this

Comment: @SunilDubey It works, take a look https://mongoplayground.net/p/aYyXMBHNpn6

Comment: added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504061/mongodb-compare-one-collection-to-other-collection

Comment: please help on our code added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504061/mongodb-compare-one-collection-to-other-collection

Comment: See https://mongoplayground.net/p/vaYpoxJZhT5 its not working it should return nothing when I change specified id 5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764 it works fine please guide you can see both date is higher then main collection that's the part I touching from last one hour.

Comment: It is only checking with last object it should check all object inside history collection